# Copy space delimited string columns to list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to copy the content of a space delimited .txt file into separate lists corresponding to the columns, but I could not find a way to solve this.

A sample of a .txt file is this:

```
Product 6153990c-14fa-47d2-81cf-a253f9294f96 - Date: 2016-06-29T09:47:27Z, Instrument: MSI, Mode: , Satellite: Sentinel-2, Size: 3.08 GB

Product cac95c2a-2d6e-477a-848f-caccbd219d39 - Date: 2016-06-29T09:47:27Z, Instrument: MSI, Mode: , Satellite: Sentinel-2, Size: 6.32 GB

Product c65147d3-ee3c-4f33-9e09-ea234d3543f7 - Date: 2016-06-29T09:40:32Z, Instrument: MSI, Mode: , Satellite: Sentinel-2, Size: 4.00 GB

Product fd1860e3-5d57-429e-b0c7-628a07b4bd5c - Date: 2016-06-27T09:03:49Z, Instrument: MSI, Mode: , Satellite: Sentinel-2, Size: 6.25 GB

Product ba8e4be4-502a-4986-94ce-d0f4dec23b5c - Date: 2016-06-27T09:03:49Z, Instrument: MSI, Mode: , Satellite: Sentinel-2, Size: 5.52 GB

Product b95cb837-6606-484b-89d6-b10bfaead9bd - Date: 2016-06-26T09:30:35Z, Instrument: MSI, Mode: , Satellite: Sentinel-2, Size: 5.81 GB

Product 96b64cfe-fc2e-4808-8356-2760d9671839 - Date: 2016-06-26T09:30:35Z, Instrument: MSI, Mode: , Satellite: Sentinel-2, Size: 6.14 GB

Product 20bb3c9e-bd15-417a-8713-3ece6090dd95 - Date: 2016-06-24T08:51:49Z, Instrument: MSI, Mode: , Satellite: Sentinel-2, Size: 4.89 GB

Product 5bf78d9b-a12b-4e54-aba7-299ae4ac0756 - Date: 2016-06-24T08:51:49Z, Instrument: MSI, Mode: , Satellite: Sentinel-2, Size: 5.93 GB
```

If I split the file using the space delimiter, the columns will be (commas are included in some columns):

```
Product
59337094-226a-4d64-94b1-3fee5f5cbfe2
-
Date: 
2016-07-26T09:30:38Z, 
Instrument:
MSI, 
Mode: 
,
Satellite: 
Sentinel-2, 
Size:
5.07
GB
```

What I tried doing is (example for the first column):

```
list = []
with open('D:\GIS\Sentinel\cmd_output.txt', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader (file, delimiter = ' ')
    for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n in reader:
        list.append(a) 
print list
```

But it doesn't work and send the error:

> ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

How can I do this for each of the columns in file?
Thanks!

Comment: If you are sure that you're using a correct delimiter you'd wrap your unpacking part within a `try-except` in order to handle the defective rows.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I am not and advanced user of Python.

Comment: can you show the actual traceback?  Why are you just appending a?   It holds the value 'Product' it seems?

Comment: Read the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Do you have blank lines in your file?

Comment: @ joel goldstick: traceback sends to the for loop. @ReutSharabani: I don't have blank lines

Comment: @Litwos your example data clearly has blank lines. Should they be removed from the question?

Comment: @PaulRooney: I inserted them in the example here, because I could not split the rows in the code-block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `reader` variable does not have the shape you think, see :
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader
"Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings."

So you should probably try for your first column :

```
list = []
with open('D:\GIS\Sentinel\cmd_output.txt', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader (file, delimiter = ' ')
    for row in reader:
        list.append(row[0]) 
print list
```

Comment: This works and I think is faster than Rhaul KP's answer.

Comment: Glad to have helped !

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this with basic `split` like this.

```
file_pointer = open('a.txt')
text = file_pointer.read()
major_list = []
filtered_list = [i for i in text.split('\n') if i]
for item in filtered_list:
    major_list.append(item.split())
first_row = [item[0] for item in major_list]
second_row = [item[1] for item in major_list]
#As may you want.
```